# How do I prove this with relationship properties?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, education, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ be a set and think of $\subseteq$ as defining a relation on $\mathcal{P}(A)$, i.e.,

$R = \{(X, Y ) : X \subseteq Y \}$.

Is it an equivalence relation or an order relation? The question asks for a justified answer.

I'm not sure as to how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should just look at what the definitions of an order relation and an equivalence relation are. Does the relation $R$ satisfy these definitions?

Hint: is this relation $R$ symmetric?